# I have issue with Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, fancyform

I have used fancybox for contact form. and its open on page load. so i have used following code .

```
jQuery.fancybox.open('#fancy');
```

I am already try this but fancybox not open on load.

```
jQuery("#fancy").fancybox({
        openEffect : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade',
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
```

});

But when i click on outside the fancybox its close i need only close on close button.

Comment: Are you using version 1 or 2, plz?

Comment: i am using  version 2

Answer (score 0):

This way will close only on close button

```
(function($){

var closeByButton = false;

$(("#fancy").fancybox({
    openEffect : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    padding: 0,
    beforeLoad : function() {
        closeByButton = false;
    },
    beforeClose: function() {
        if(!closeByButton){
            return false;
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseenter','.fancybox-close', function(){
    closeByButton = true;
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.fancybox-close', function(){
    closeByButton = false;
});
```

Comment: Please read bounty condition i also want to on mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try with option `autoSize: true`. It will auto resize on mobile view also.

Check Working Demo **[Here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/VKNRGB)**

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'fade',
  closeEffect: 'fade',
  autoSize: true,
  helpers: {
    overlay: {
      css: {
        cursor: 'auto'
      },
      closeClick: false
    }
  }
  }).trigger("click");
});
```

To fix scrolling issue add the following style

CSS:

```
body .fancybox-wrap {
  position: fixed!important;
}
```